# Map API to Generate Routes Based on Distance

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I am looking for a Javascript API like Google Maps which can produce routes based on distance criteria.  For example, I give a start point and an end point which are the same and I want 5-10 different routes which start and end there but are about 5 miles long.  Is there anything out there which can do that?

I know that Google Maps can do that with just a start and end but no distance parameter. I just want to have distance be a parameter and have the start and end points be the same.

Comment: I'm not aware of any API that will do this easily... I'm curious about what you're wanting to accomplish. Just to make sure I understand, you don't want any particular end point, but a random route from start, going 5 miles and back to start?

Comment: That is correct.  Pretty much I just want to find a loop of distance X with start/end point Y

Comment: Been thinking about this for a while. I don't know of a really good way to do this. My first thought would be to use the places api to grab a few destinations in a radius around your start point, and chain a few of those in a directions request and render it with the directions renderer. Good luck, if you find a good way to do this, you should post it as the answer and accept it.

Comment: Here is an [example](http://maps.forum.nu/gm_driving_radius.html) that might help (using the v2 Google Maps API though).